# $n>m$ so $w_1,...,w_n$ are linearly dependent theorem doubts

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Theorem**: Let V be a vector space over the field $K$. Let $\{v_1,...,v_m\}$ be a basis of $V$ over $K$.Let $w_1,...,w_n$ be elements of $V$, and assume that $n>m$. Then $w_1,...,w_n$ are linearly dependent.
>
> ***Proof***: Since  $\{v_1,...,v_m\}$ is a basis , there exists elements $a_1,...,a_m\in K $ such that $w_1=a_1v_1+...+a_mv_m$.
>
> By assumption, we know that $w_1\neq 0$, and hence some $a_i\neq 0$. After renumbering $v_1,...,v_m$ if necessary, we may assume without loss of generality that say $a_1\neq 0$. We can then solve for $v_1$, and get
>
> $a_1v_1=w_1-a_2v_2-...-a_mv_m,\\v_1=a_1^{-1}w_1-a_1^{-1}a_2v_2-...-a_1^{-1}a_mv_m$.
>
> The subspace of $V$ generated by $w_1,v_2,...,v_m$ contains $v_1$, and hence must be all of $V$ since $\{v_1,v_2...,v_m\}$ contains $v_1$, and hence must be all of $V$ since $v_1,v_2,...,v_m$ generate $V$. The idea is now to continue our procedure stepwise, and to replace successively $v_2,v_3...$ by $w_2,w_3...$ until all the elements $v_1,...,v_m$ are exhausted, and $w_1,...,w_m$ generate V. Let us now assume by induction that there is an integer $r$ with $1\leqslant r<m$ such that, after a suitable renumbering of $v_1,...,v_m$, the elelments $w_1,...,w_r,v_{r+1},...,v_m$ generate $V$. There exist elements $b_1,...,b_r,c_{r+1}...,c_m$ in $K$ such that:
>
> $w_{r+1}=b_1w_1+...+b_rw_r+c_{r+1}v_{r+1}+...+c_mv_m$.
>
> We cannot have $c_j=0$ for $j=r+1,...,m$, for otherwise, we get a relation of linear dependence between $w_1,...,w_{r+1}$, contradicting our assumption. After renumbering $v_{r+1},...,v_m$ if necessary, we may assume without loss of generality that say $c_{r+1}\neq 0$. We then obtain:
>
> $c_{r+1}v_{r+1}=w_{r+1}-b_1w_1-...-b_rW_r-c_{r+1}v_{r+1}+...+c_mv_m$.
>
> Dividing by $c_{r+1}$, we conclude that $v_{r+1}$ is in the subspace generated by $w_1,...,w_{r+1},v_{r+2},...,v_m$. But our induction assumption, it follows that $w_1,...,w_{r+1},v_{r+2},...,v_m$ generate $V$. Thus by induction, we have proved that $w_1,...,w_m$ generate $V$. If $n>m$ then there exists elements
>
> $d_1,...,d_m\in K$ such that $w_n=d_1 w_1+...+d_mw_m$,
>
> thereby proving that $w_1,...,w_n$ are linearly dependent. This proves our theorem.$\blacksquare$*Linear Algebra by Serge Lang*

I am self-studying however I have some doubts about this theorem.

**Questions**:

**1)** How do I get this expression$w_{r+1}=b_1w_1+...+b_rw_r+c_{r+1}v_{r+1}+...+c_mv_m$ from the previews one?

**2)** How do I know "We cannot have $c_j=0$ for $j=r+1,...,m$, for otherwise, we get a relation of linear dependence between $w_1,...,w_{r+1}$"? There is no assumption the w_s are linearly dependent.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be easier to suppose that $\{w_1,...,w_m\}$ is linearly independent, and express each $w_i$ as a linear combination of $v_1,...,v_m,$ and use the row-reduction algorithm and the linear independence of $\{w_1,...,w_m\}$ to show that each $v_i$ is a linear combination of $w_1,...,w_m.$  But then $w_{m+1}$ is seen to be a linear combination of $w_1,...,w_m.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

**1)** Try to go from $w_1$ to $w_2$. Applying similar computations inductively will produce the desired expression for $w_{r+1}$.

**2)** If I'm not wrong, this should read "We must have $c_j \neq 0$ for some $j \in \{ r+1, r+2, \dots, m\}$".

Comment: Re: (2), that's exactly what it says: there's an implicit "all" there. It's definitely not very clear, but the line in the text does say what you want it to. The OP's point is that there isn't in fact a contradiction here since the $w_i$s weren't assumed to be linearly independent.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yeah I agree that it should have been mentioned at the beginning that it's proof by contradiction.

Comment: @NoahSchweber In fact I made an implicit assumption in my own mind that it's proof by contradiction, hence didn't pay too much attention to the fact that this should be mentioned explicitly.

Comment: I tried to derive $w_2$. Here it is $w_2=a_1^{-1}w_1-a_1^{-1}a_2v_2-...-a_1^{-1}a_mv_m\\v_2=a_2^{-1}w_1-a_2^{-1}w_2-...-a_2^{-1}a_m v_m\\w_3=a_2^{-1}w_1-a_2^{-1}w_2-...-a_2^{-1}a_m v_m$, so on but$ b_i=a_r$ which is weird. Because $b_1=b_2=...b_r=a_r$,right?

Comment: Follow these steps: Assume $w_1 = a_{11} v_1 + a_{12} v_2 + \cdots + a_{1m} v_m$, $w_2 = a_{21} v_1 + a_{22} v_2 + \cdots + a_{2m} v_m$. Then, Step 1. Express $v_1$ in terms of $a_{ij}$'s and $w_1, v_2, \dots, v_m$. Step 2. Substitute the expression for $v_1$ in second equation, simplify, and combine coefficients of $v_2$. So RHS in the expression for $w_2$ now contains $w_1, v_2, \dots, v_m$, but no $v_1$. Step 3. Now represent $v_2$ in terms of $w_1, w_2, v_3, \dots, v_m$. Step 4. See that this process can be carried over to $w_{r+1}$.

Comment: The expressions keep getting really messy. And anyways, you don't need explicit expressions. All you need is an argument that this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

I think for Q2, the author meant to add at the beginning the assumption for contradiction that the $w_s$s are linearly independent; after all, we're trying to prove that they *aren't*, so we can assume they *are* at the beginning to perform a proof by contradiction.

For Q1, remember that by assumption the set $A_r=\{w_1, ..., w_r, v_{r+1}, ..., v_m\}$ generates $V$. This means that every element of $V$ - in particular, $w_{r+1}$ - can be written as a linear combination of the elements in $A_r$; and this means exactly that $$w_{r+1}=b_1w_1+...+b_rw_r+c_{r+1}v_{r+1}+...+c_nv_m$$ for some choice of coefficients $b_1, ..., b_r, c_{r+1}, ..., c_m$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But on Q1 I am talking about the derivation. How do I derive $w_{r+1}=b_1w_1+...+b_rw_r+c_{r+1}v_{r+1}+...+c_nv_m$?

Comment: @PedroGomes This is exactly what I said in my answer: because the set $\{w_1, ..., w_r, v_{r+1}, ..., v_m\}$ - by induction hypothesis *(see the part beginning " Let us now assume by induction ...")* - generates $V$. And $w_{r+1}$ is an element in $V$, so it is a linear combination of those vectors (remember that this is exactly what "generates" means).

Comment: I tried to derive $w_{r+1}=b_1w_1+...+b_rw_r+c_{r+1}v_{r+1}+...+c_nv_m$ but the coeficients $b_i=a_r^{-1}$ which is weird considering coefficients b have different indexes.

Comment: @PedroGomes What? There's no need to compute the $b_i$s or $c_j$s. We just need that they *exist*. And this follows from the definition of "generates" - do you understand this? (And I don't see where you're getting "$b_i=a_r^{-1}$" from.)

Comment: Here it is $w_2=a_1^{-1}w_1-a_1^{-1}a_2v_2-...-a_1^{-1}a_mv_m\\v_2=a_2^{-1}w_1-a_2^{-1}w_2-...-a_2^{-1}a_m v_m\\w_3=a_2^{-1}w_1-a_2^{-1}w_2-...-a_2^{-1}a_m v_m$, so on but$ b_i=a_r$ which is weird. Because $b_1=b_2=...b_r=a_r$,right?

Comment: @PedroGomes Combining Noah Schweber's and my answer, try to compute the coefficients explicitly for $w_2$, to see that this computation can be done "in principle". As the comment above suggests, you don't need to compute the coefficients explicitly. All you need to show is that *this can be done*.

Comment: @PedroGomes What? Where are you getting "$w_2=a_1^{-1}w_1-a_1^{-1}a_2v_w-...-a_1^{-1}a_mv_m$" from? $a_1^{-1}w_1-a_1^{-1}a_2v_w-...-a_1^{-1}a_mv_m$" is $v_1$, not $w_2$.

Comment: @PedroGomes If you are getting confused with $a_i$'s, look at it this way.. Let $w_1 = a_{11} v_1 + a_{12} v_2 + \cdots + a_{1m} v_m$, $w_2 = a_{21} v_1 + a_{22} v_2 + \cdots + a_{2m} v_m$ and so on.. then carry out the computations again. Note that the coefficients $a_i$'s must be different for $w_1$, $w_2$, ...

Comment: @NoahSchweber  $a_1^{-1}w_1-a_1^{-1}a_2v_w-...-a_1^{-1}a_mv_m$ are linear independent since they generate $v_1$ so this same expression can generate any element in $V$ as the proof states, right?

Comment: @PedroGomes You need to see that *given a basis for $V$*, two different vectors in $V$ have different representations in terms of *that basis*. You cannot keep writing $w_1$ and $w_2$ using same coefficients $a_i$'s.

Comment: @jgsmath    Of course you are right. How do I derive $w_{r+1}=b_1w_1+...+b_rw_r+c_{r+1}v_{r+1}+...+c_nv_m$ ? Could you do it on your answer section please?

Comment: @PedroGomes **I DID ALREADY**. Given any vector in $V$, there is some choice of $b_i, c_j$ such that $b_1w_1+...+b_rw_r+c_{r+1}v_{r+1}+...+c_mv_m$ equals it. I just applied this to the vector $w_{r+1}$. The coefficients **are chosen to make the equality hold** - note the phrase "There exist elements $b_1, ..., b_r, c_{r+1}, ..., c_m$ in $K$ such that ...." There is no "derivation" to do, we know by assumption that some such set of coefficients exists and we pick one and use it.